# Can we set the collation in insert statement?

Tags: mysql, database, collation

I am trying to set the database collation at introducer level. But when I am fetching the data from the table I see different characters.

```
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test.tblname;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE test.tblname (
    ->     colnm VARCHAR(50)
    ->         CHARACTER SET euckr
    ->         COLLATE euckr_bin
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql>
mysql> INSERT INTO test.tblname VALUES (_euckr'가');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test.tblname VALUES (_euckr'각');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test.tblname VALUES (_euckr'갂');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test.tblname VALUES (_euckr'갃');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> SELECT * FROM test.tblname;
+-------+
| colnm |
+-------+
| 媛    |
| 媛    |
| 媛    |
| 媛    |
+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

When I tried to insert the data simply like "INSERT INTO test.tblname VALUES ('가');" I see the data is returned correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the introducer, but *only* if it is appropriate.

```
CONVERT(BINARY('갃') USING euckr) --> '媛'
UNHEX(HEX(CONVERT(CONVERT(UNHEX('B0A2') USING euckr) USING utf8))) --> '각'
```

That is, if you are somehow entering `B0A2` into

```
INSERT INTO test.tblname VALUES (_euckr'...');
```

then it will be inserted correctly.  Do you have a keyboard that will generate such 2-byte EUCKR codes?

For virtually all applications, use `utf8mb4`.  Use other things (such as `euckr`) only when the source bytes are in some non-UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: I don't have a special keyboard. I am generating a file with the sql statements. SQL file has all the insert statement which I am using. For example:
`INSERT INTO test.tblname VALUES (_euckr'갂');`. I am not sure how I can insert these characters with a introducer level collation.

Comment: Can you get a hex dump of that file, or at least that character.  It _should be_ `B0A2`.  If it is not, then the use of `_euckr` is probably wrong.

Answer (score 0):

An [introducer](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-literal.html) tells the parser "the string that follows uses character set charset_name.". So you are telling the parser that your character is in EUC-KR but in fact your are probably typing it in UTF8 because that's the character set of your client (you can verify this with: `show variables like 'character_set_client';`)

You should pay attention to this:

> Query OK, 1 row affected, **2 warnings** (0.00 sec)

Use `show warnings;` after an insert to show the warnings. You probably have one that says "Incorrect string value".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked the warnings and yes it shows me warning  like "Incorrect string value".   Also I modified the global variable value for 'character_set_client' to 'euckr' but I see the same result.

Comment: Why did you modify `character_set_client`? Are you typing in euc-kr? Is your terminal in euc-kr? As I said, you are very probably typing in utf8, and therefore you do *not* need to use an introducer. Type in utf8, have `character_set_client` in utf8, and MySQL will do the conversion to the table's character set. You even said it yourself in your question, it works fine without introducer, so I don't understand why you are trying to use one.